# Check if argument is correctly passed to a shell script

Tags: linux, shell

I am writing a shell script where i need to pass an argument on executing. My question is how to check if the argument is with matching the given pattern. Example:

```
./script.sh 1 - 9
```

In this example, `1 - 9` thing is only one argument and the pattern is `"%s - %s"`. How to check if matches the pattern.
Thanks in advice

Comment: It really depends on how complicated the pattern is. In your example, you get 3 arguments (no quotation marks), and you just need to check `$2` agains `-`. The `case` operation can also do some pattern matching. For really weird patterns, I'd probably call `perl -e` with a one line regular expression and suitable print command.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The three main programs I use in shell scripts are sed, grep, and awk. The cool thing about each is regular expressions. In the shell, $@ is all positional parameters, so you can echo $@ and pipe it into awk or grep.

```
echo $@ | awk '/\S+ - \S+/ {print}'
```

With grep you can test the return value, $?:

```
$ echo 1 - 9 | egrep '\S+ - \S+'
1 - 9
$ echo $?
0
$ echo  - 9 | egrep '\S+ - \S+'
$ echo $?
1
```

Check the return value with test:

```
ARGS="$@"
MATCH=$(echo "$ARGS" | egrep '^\S+ - \S+')
if [ $? = 0 ]
then
  echo "good match"
fi
```

Or using MATCH above:

```
if [ -n "$MATCH" ]
then
  echo "good match"
fi
```